# How to stop Sublime Text Elm Language Support from creating new elm-package.json files?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, elm, package-control

Every time I open an **Elm** file in **Sublime Text** after installing [the Elm Language Support package](https://github.com/elm-community/Elm.tmLanguage), it generates a new `elm-package.json` file in the file's directory, even though I already have an `elm-package.json` file in the project's root. Behavior goes away if I uninstall the package. Created an issue [here](https://github.com/elm-community/Elm.tmLanguage/issues/10) but I thought I would ask Stack Overflow as well in case it's something I need to do on my end.

Comment: This issue is with the Python code in the plugin, so it will have to be addressed by the author(s). From what I can tell, the plugin is attempting to search for an `elm-package.json` file before writing, but apparently it's failing for some reason.